# Use of diode got problem

Tags: diodes

I want to use diode on 240V because I do not want current to flow in reverse direction. I use it and everything is ok except voltage drop. Actually diode drop voltage from 240V to 120V. How  can I get 240V by using a diode?

Thanks for answer. Because actually I have three toilet on my job and client want to use sencer for light and toilet fan to work. All three toilet have big one fan. So problem is when one sensor work other 2 toilet light goes on. Because all switch live combined in fan. That's why I want to use diode so when fan work no light goes on in another 2 toilet. Please do you have any other idea

Comment: Can you provide more information on your problem? A circuit diagram would be helpful.

Comment: Which diode? What's the schematic?

Comment: Are you using 240 volts AC (like from an outlet in your house?)

Comment: A normal silicon diode would drop about 1V not 120V. So you are doing something wrong. With no schematic, we have no idea what.

Comment: Diodes won't do what you want.

Comment: A diode can block 1/2 of Vac to get 1/2 rectified power.  Do you have 3 sensors, 3 lights and 1 shared fan and are wondering why any sensor turns on all Lights and Fan

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are half-wave rectifying the mains when you should be full-wave rectifying the mains. There are thousands of articles on this topic on the Internet.

[image]

*Figure 1. Half-wave rectification. Image source: [Electronics-Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_5.html).*

It also sounds as though you shouldn't be doing this work on 240 V circuits with such poor understanding of the principles involved.

Comment: Definitely should not be touching 240V circuit with such poor understanding.  Very dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Diodes will not work and can damage your fan. What you need is 3x SPST relays with 240VAC coils and rated to switch your fan motor load.

The relays have contacts isolated from the coils so they prevent "backflow".

In the schematic below, SW1..3 represent the individual pyroelectric sensor units, each switching a single cubicle lamp. One relay coil is connected across each lamp.

When any one or more light(s) is on, the respective relay(s) actuate and power the fan. The fan only goes off when all three lights are extinguished.

It sounds like you should get a qualified local electrician involved in this installation **and** selection process, however, to make sure you meet local electrical codes and the installation is safe, especially in a bathroom. If you show him or her the diagram they should understand and be able to help implement it. Just selecting the relay contact rating requires a certain amount of knowledge.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP5heA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You are so genius.  Thanks for solving my problem.  Can I use contactor switch instead of relay switch. I know they both work with emf ( induction). Any way thanks so much

Comment: Yes, contactors have a similar function to normally open relay.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use four relays, three for the lamps and one for the exhaust fan.

[image]

As the lights and the fan are separately switched, there is no question of reverse current flow.

Comment: Hi. I do try to find relay switch but they said it will not stop reverse current to flow

Comment: @Garry, you are not qualified and have not enough knowledge to do this work. Please find someone qualified to do this work safely. It's probably a legal requirement in your country.